# Is there a standard API definition for browser engines?

Tags: browser, webkit, chromium, gecko

We know that there are many browser engines, such as WebKit, Chromium, Gecko, and others. But is there a standard browser engine API definition? I think with that, I could implement an application that quickly switches between browser engines.

Comment: There's no such thing as standards for browser engine and there's no standards for interfacing with browser engines either